# Value Error while bucketing data using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was working on a pandas dataframe, data snippet shown below:

Insurance data:

[image]

I wanted to bucket the 'bmi' column and tried using this code:

---

```
if (df['bmi'] < 18.5):
  df.bmi_category='underweight'
elif (df['bmi'] >= 18.5 & df['bmi'] < 24.9):
    df.bmi_category='normal'
else:
    df.bmi_category='overweight'
```

This code is throwing:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, 
a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Please help in resolving this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfect case to use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

> Return an array drawn from elements in choicelist, depending on conditions.

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': {0: 'Louis', 1: 'Paul', 2: 'Alex'},
                   'bmi': {0: 12, 1: 20, 2: 31}})

df['bmi_category'] = np.select([df['bmi'] < 18.5, df['bmi'] >= 24.9],
                               ['underweight', 'overweighted'], default='normal')
```

```
>>> df
    name  bmi  bmi_category
0  Louis   12   underweight
1   Paul   20        normal
2   Alex   31  overweighted
```